# How to make layout for Nexus4 and Galaxy Nexus separately?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make my calculator app to be compatible with all types of screens.
These are my layout folders:

- layout-large
- layout-normal
- layout-small
- layout-sw360dp
- layout-sw360dp-large
- layout-sw360dp-xlarge
- layout-xhdpi
- layout-xlarge

in this case, Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 uses the same layout for some reason: layout-sw360dp, but their layout isn't matching. If I change it for the Nexus 4, it will screw up the Galaxy Nexus:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Nexus 4 use: `layout-xhdpi` folder .

For Galaxy Nexus use: `layout-sw360dp` folder.

Comment: I figured out that layout-sw360dp-long is perfect for the Galaxy Nexus but it also works with your answer, so I used your version. Thank you

Comment: adding -long didn't work for me, maybe it's the fact I'm building for API 19?  Try sw384dp if this doesn't work for you.